# How to read pyspark avro file and extract the values?

Tags: python, pyspark

How to read the twitter.avro files in pyspark and **extract the values from it?**

`rdd=sc.textFile("twitter.asvc")` is working good

But when I do

```
rdd1=sc.textFile("twitter.avro")
rdd1.collect()
```

I am getting output below

> ['Obj\x01\x02\x16avro.schema\x04{"type":"record","name":"episodes","namespace":"testing.hive.avro.serde","fields":[{"name":"title","type":"string","doc":"episode
>   title"},{"name":"air_date","type":"string","doc":"initial
>   date"},{"name":"doctor","type":"int","doc":"main actor playing the
>   Doctor in episode"}]}\x00kR\x03LS\x17m|]Z^{0\x10\x04"The Eleventh
>   Hour\x183 April 2010\x16"The Doctor\'s Wife\x1614 May 2011\x16&Horror
>   of Fang Rock 3 September 1977\x08$An Unearthly Child 23 November
>   1963\x02*The Mysterious Planet 6 September 1986\x0c\x08Rose\x1a26
>   March 2005\x12.The Power of the Daleks\x1e5 November
>   1966\x04\x14Castrolava\x1c4 January 1982', 'kR\x03LS\x17m|]Z^{0']

Is there a python library for reading this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a FileInputFormat specific for Avro files.

Unfortunately I am not using python so I can only link you to a solution. You can look into that: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/avro_inputformat.py

The most interesting part is this one:

```
avro_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    path,
    "org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat",
    "org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    keyConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.AvroWrapperToJavaConverter",
    conf=conf)
```

Comment: thanks Dawid How to set Classplath?org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat",
    "org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    keyConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.AvroWrapperToJavaConverter

Comment: Try reading the attached repo. I think you will find all needed info there. As for classpath: `./bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /path/to/example/jar \
... `